# Maintain a sorted list using realm in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, fastadapter

I am pulling all my data from realm and displaying initially in a sorted list.Whenever items are added or removed or modified to this list i would like it to still be sorted.Is there a way realm can manage this sorted list internally and update the adapter or do i need a change listener and then manually sort it?

Comment: use `findAllSorted()` or `findAllSortedAsync()`

Comment: I have done that ,it would give me an initial sorted list, when i add a new item or delete or update an item i would like the list to be up to date without fetching the entire list all over again from realm and applying it.

Comment: well yes, that is  why you use `findAllSorted()`/`findAllSortedAsync()`, because it does exactly that

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so whenever a CRUD operation occurs how would i reflect that change to the recycler view?

Comment: if you are using a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` from `realm-android-adapters` then if you provide the `RealmResults` to the adapter directly, then this is entirely automatic and you don't need to do anything beyond using `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` with `true` for auto-updates